# How to split a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have very basic C code and I have a simple question. 
I searched google for my problem but I can't find anything that help me out. So, my problem is that I need to split a string and output two strings as a result. I know about `strcpy` but it doesn't work with me.

Assume we have a string:

```
stringOne("http://google.com/logo.jpg C:\windows\user\Desktop\logo.jpg");
```

I want to copy "http://google.com/logo.jpg" into another string,

```
stringTow("http://google.com/logo.jpg");
```

and if I `cout << stringTwo << endl;`

it will show http://google.com/logo.jpg

and `"C:\windows\user\Desktop\logo.jpg"` into another string,

```
stringThree("C:\windows\user\Desktop\logo.jpg");
```

Sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: You should excuse more for your missing c++ code, than (not that) poor english!

Comment: Are you looking for C code (as described in the question and title) or C++ code (as described in the tag)?  You're sending mixed signals, which is confusing.

Comment: Are you talking about 'C' strings (`char str[]`s) or are you talking about C++ `std::string`s?

Comment: If this is C code, look up `strcspn()` or `strpbrk()`.  You could also use `strtok()` as long as the strings are not string literals, though `strtok()` is not the nicest function in the world.  If you're using C++ and the `std::string` type, you do things differently.

Comment: _'it will show http://google.com/logo.jpg'_ ?!?!? Serious misconceptions you have?

Comment: your title shows C and your tag says C++, make up your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about C++'s `std::string`, there are a variety of ways you could do this, for instance you can use string.find and string.assign.

For other ways of doing it, take a look at the [std::string member functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int /*argc*/, const char** /*argv*/)
{
    std::string stringOne = "http://google.com/logo.jpg C:\\windows\\user\\Desktop\\logo.jpg";
    std::string stringTwo = "", stringThree = "";

    size_t spacePos = stringOne.find(' ');
    if (spacePos != std::string::npos) {
        // copy 0-spacePos, i.e. all the chars before the space.
        stringTwo.assign(stringOne, 0, spacePos);
        // copy everything after the space.
        stringThree.assign(stringOne, spacePos + 1, std::string::npos);
    }

    std::cout << "s1 = \"" << stringOne << "\"" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s2 = \"" << stringTwo << "\"" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s3 = \"" << stringThree << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

Live demo here: http://ideone.com/t2MEiD

Comment: the example code above assumes you wanted to split it based on the string, so it uses `stringOne.find(' ')` to find the position of the space, and then creates a string from the left and right sides of that position.

Comment: yes im talking about c++,
thank you sir, amin__
thank you kfsone
thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Use this way,

```
   char str[] = "http://google.com/logo.jpg C:\windows\\user\Desktop\logo.jpg";
   char *string1;   
   char *string2;
   string1 = strtok(str, " ");
   printf("%s\n",string1);

   string2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
   printf("%s\n",string2);
```